# Create keyboard event

Tags: android, keyevent

I try to create an keyboard event following an action. Then, I want get this event on an other application.

I have use, Instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(int keycode);
But when I execute, I have the error :

> Permission denied: injecting event from pid 2121 uid 10082 to window
>
> Window{2be943e0 u0 com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}
> owned by uid 10081
>
> threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b7fb930)
>
> Sending signal. PID: 2121 SIG: 9
>
> Input event injection from pid 2121 permission denied.
>
> FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-126
>
> java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires > INJECT_EVENTS permission

I have added on my two manifest (application which create KeyEvent and application which received "KeyEvent"), the permisssion :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"></uses-permission>
```

I have tested to install application directly with copy apk on /system/app without succeed.

Have you any idea about the problem ?
Is there any other solution to create a KeyEvent ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `INJECT_EVENTS` is a `signature`-level permission. You cannot hold it just by being installed on the system partition. You would have to be signed by the firmware's signing key (e.g., your app would be part of a custom ROM). The `Instrumentation` code that you are trying to use is for testing, and that can be used from test suites, but not from production apps.

Comment: Ok, thak you for your answer. Is there any other solution to emit keyevent from application ?

Comment: Not really. The accessibility framework offers some features in this area, but it's not designed for arbitrary keypresses AFAIK.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is writing a software keyboard that automatically inject keystrokes.  However, it can only work on EditText as that's what software keyboards are for.  What are you trying to accomplish? If you are trying to test your own app, please use proper testing tools like Espresso, Robotium, or UIAutomator.

Comment: In fact, I get event from hid device (read by UsbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfert) on a background Service. I want transform this data to keyboard event and dispatch to other application